# MariaDB/MySQL : Is there a command similar to ATTACH DATABASE from SQLite3

Tags: mysql, sqlite, mariadb

Is there a command similar to ATTACH DATABASE from SQLite3 for MariaDB/MySQL or an alternative ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the intentions?

If you want to do a query cross-database, you just append the table name with database name plus dot. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM db_name.table_name WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: There's also the `USE db_name;` statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html

Comment: Yes thank you with a INNER JOIN and it is perfect for what i want to do :)